# How to run same sql with different data for a large number of times

Tags: sql, database, oracle, loops, cursor

I have to update some data into a db based on a particular value of a column c1 in my table, now i have to do the same thing for various values for c1 but i cant use if/else as there are too many cases i was think of a solution using cursors but i have not much experience with them(or any at all for that matter) plz help me.

I have:

- Table `TAB1`
- List of value pairs (V1, V2)
- SQL statement to run for the list

  ```
  UPDATE TAB1 SET C1=V2 where C1=V1
  ```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Is the list of value pairs also going to be in a table as well?

Comment: no thats a list i have in notepad

Comment: @MozenRath You can `JOIN` these values as a table with the `UPDATE` statement. But is this applicable in your case? Can you create a temp table of these values? Please try to give a sample data.

Comment: How you are planning to consume data from notepad ? Are you going to create any GUI part for it.

Comment: I was thinking of copying them on to the sql from notepad in the form of an array or something similar. please advise whats best.

Comment: You can use OracleBulkCopy or you can create a stored procedure for this update and pass those values as parameters to that stored procedure.

Comment: hmm... I wanted to do this without creating any persistent data/objects on the DB

Comment: There are many ways.one of them is you can use Filestream to read data from notepad,convert to byte array and convert it to file while updating data into db.

Comment: can you please give detailed info in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one-off job then with a decent column-based text editor you can modify your data set from:

```
1 2
3 4
```

... to ...

```
select 1 v1 2 v2 from dual union all
select 3 v1 4 v2 from dual union all
```

... etc, and then use it as part of a merge statement that would avoid the need to deal with update join cardinality checks

```
merge into tab1 using (
select 1 v1 2 v2 from dual union all
select 3 v1 4 v2 from dual union all
... ) src
on (src.v1 = tab1.c1)
when ... etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a cursor for this operation. If you have the value pairs in a table, just use:

```
UPDATE 
  ( SELECT t.C1, vp.V2
    FROM 
        TAB1 t 
      JOIN
        ValuePairs vp
          ON t.C1 = vp.V1
  ) tmp 
SET C1 = V2 ;
```

If it's only a list, you can use a derived table:

```
UPDATE 
  ( SELECT t.C1, vp.V2
    FROM 
        TAB1 t 
      JOIN
        ( SELECT 1 V1, 2 V2 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 3 FROM dual
        -- ...

        UNION ALL
          SELECT 19, 23 FROM dual 
        ) vp
          ON t.C1 = vp.V1
  ) tmp 
SET C1 = V2 ;
```

Comment: i dont have it in a table but on my notepad

Comment: @MozenRath why not save your notepad list to a temp table and follow ypercube's way (either the update he wrote or a merge)?

Comment: hmm... just realized that there is no simple way to it :P. Will create a table fr temporary. although wanted to avoid that, I will just need to delete it later

Answer (score -1):

```
    you can try like this without creating the table.

    bytes = readFile(FilenamewithPath);
    file = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    public static byte[] readFile(bool delFileOnRead, string fileNameWithPath)
   {
     try {
                FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(fileNameWithPath, FileMode.Open,   FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] retVal = new byte[fsSource.Length];
                int numBytesToRead = (int)fsSource.Length;
                int numBytesRead = 0;
                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    int n = fsSource.Read(retVal, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
                    if (n == 0)
                        break;
                    numBytesRead += n;
                    numBytesToRead -= n;
                }
                fsSource.Close();
                fsSource.Dispose();
                if (delFileOnRead)
                {
                    File.Delete(fileNameWithPath);
                }
                return retVal;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```